# VBA - Loop through files in a folder ONLY if file not already included in a list

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently using a piece of code to loop through all files in a folder and copy certain cells from each file into a master list. Currently there are a number of files being added into the folder every week. The code is then re-ran and all files are looped through again. One of the columns in the master list includes the filenames of previously looped files.

I would like to modify this code to **ONLY** loop through files that have not previously been looped through (i.e files with filenames that are not already included in the list created by previously running the code) and add data into the already existing list. Here is the code that I am currently using:

```
Sub CopyFromFolderExample()
    ' updated 2018-11-13 by OPE
    ' copies values from the first worksheet from all workbooks in a given folder
    Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String, r As Long, wb As Workbook
    Dim varTemp(1 To 6) As Variant ' variable to hold the values you want to copy

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    strFolder = "D:\Other\Barbara's Bakery Ltd\Inv\" ' include last path separator

    ' prepare the target worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        .Range("A4:E" & .Rows.Count).ClearContents ' clear any existing content below the header row
        r = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' last non-empty row in column A
    End With

    strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.xl*") ' the first workbook found in the folder
    Do While Len(strFile) > 0 ' repeat for each *.xl* file in the folder
        Application.StatusBar = "Reading data from " & strFile & "..."
        Set wb = Workbooks.Add(strFolder & strFile) 'open a copy of the workbook, just in case it is already open
        With wb.Worksheets(1) ' specify source worksheet
            ' read input values
            varTemp(1) = .Range("A13").Value
            varTemp(2) = .Range("H8").Value
            varTemp(3) = .Range("H9").Value
            varTemp(4) = .Range("H36").Value
            varTemp(5) = .Range("H37").Value
            varTemp(6) = strFile
        End With
        wb.Close False ' close the workbook copy, not necessary to save any changes

        ' write the values from the source workbook to the target worksheet
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
            r = r + 1
            .Range("A" & r & ":F" & r).Formula = varTemp
        End With
        strFile = Dir ' next source workbook
    Loop
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you appear to be storing your previously looped book names in `Column F`, you can just look for your current books name there. If the book name is there, we will skip the file. If the book name is not there, we will proceed with your code.

---

You can use a function `Looped` to check for your value which will return either

- `TRUE`: The book has already been looped
- `FALSE`: The book has not been looped

You then need to build your action statements around the result of this function. `If Not Looped(strFile, ws) Then` which translates to `If Looped = FALSE Then` proceed.

I also declared a worksheet variable `ws` to get rid of two of your with blocks and to be able to pass this variable into the below function.

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyFromFolderExample()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String, r As Long, wb As Workbook
Dim varTemp(1 To 6) As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
strFolder = "D:\Other\Barbara's Bakery Ltd\Inv\"

    ws.Range("A4:E" & ws.Rows.Count).ClearContents
    r = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.xl*")
    Do While Len(strFile) > 0
        If Not Looped(strFile, ws) Then
            Application.StatusBar = "Reading data from " & strFile & "..."
            Set wb = Workbooks.Add(strFolder & strFile)
            With wb.Worksheets(1)
                varTemp(1) = .Range("A13").Value
                varTemp(2) = .Range("H8").Value
                varTemp(3) = .Range("H9").Value
                varTemp(4) = .Range("H36").Value
                varTemp(5) = .Range("H37").Value
                varTemp(6) = strFile
            End With
            wb.Close False

            r = r + 1
            ws.Range(ws.Cells(r, 1), ws.Cells(r, 6)).Formula = varTemp
        End If    
      strFile = Dir
    Loop

Application.StatusBar = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

```
Private Function Looped(strFile As String, ws As Worksheet) As Boolean

Dim Found As Range
Set Found = ws.Range("F:F").Find(strFile)

If Found Is Nothing Then
    Looped = False
Else
    Looped = True
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Any feed back? We don't do this for free my guy :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, it all makes sense and looks like it should work. However it doesn't at the moment, I get a Subscript out of range error when I try to run it (within the looped function: set found = ws.Range("F:F").Find(strFile, LookIn:=xlWhole). Trying to digest it all at the moment. Will get back to you if I get it working. In the meantime any ideas on why this error is popping up?

Comment: Thanks! It worked, however needed to get rid of one line in the main code. Specifically ( ws.Range("A4:E" & ws.Rows.Count).ClearContents ) as this clears the worksheet in which the data is to be stored and therefore your looped function has nothing to read. Thank you again, I am new to stack overflow, is there anything I can do to show my appreciation? :D

Comment: @M.Laszkowski we show appreciation by accepting the solutions that helped you solve your problem (check mark on left). You have already done that, so thanks!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I will do just that within the next 5 mins, shall i delete the above comment to avoid confusion?

Comment: I would like to expand on this post and have asked a new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53634800/vba-loop-through-files-in-a-folder-only-if-multiple-conditions-are-met