# VBA - Loop through files in a folder ONLY if multiple conditions are met

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently using a piece of code to loop through files in a folder and copy certain cells from each file into a master list. There are a number of files being added into the folder every week. One of the columns in the master list includes the filenames of previously looped files. The code only loops through files that are not included in the filename list and therefore also have not previously been looped.

I would like to extend this and add two adjustments. I would like the code to copy an extra bit of data, however this time it is a range not just a cell (`A20:H33` specifically).When I try to change the code to copy a range the code stops working.

Furthermore, I would like to only copy data from files with a specific filename ending ("`xxxxFAM`" for example) as well as only from files that have not been looped yet - this filename ending would be chosen within a cell on the worksheet that the data is being copied to. (Cell P3 for example). Any ideas on how I might do this?

Here is the code that I am currently using and that has been kindly developed with the help of a stack overflow member! Please note that most of my work is trial and error, see below the attempts that have been made.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyFromFolderExample()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String, r As Long, wb As Workbook
Dim varTemp(1 To 6) As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
strFolder = "D:\Other\folder\"

ws.Range("A4:E" & ws.Rows.Count).ClearContents
r = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.xl*")
Do While Len(strFile) > 0
    If Not Looped(strFile, ws) Then
        Application.StatusBar = "Reading data from " & strFile & "..."
        Set wb = Workbooks.Add(strFolder & strFile)
        With wb.Worksheets(1)
            varTemp(1) = .Range("A13").Value
            varTemp(2) = .Range("H8").Value
            varTemp(3) = .Range("H9").Value
            varTemp(4) = .Range("H36").Value
            varTemp(5) = .Range("H37").Value
            varTemp(6) = strFile
        End With
        wb.Close False

        r = r + 1
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(r, 1), ws.Cells(r, 6)).Formula = varTemp
    End If    
  strFile = Dir
Loop

Application.StatusBar = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

```
Private Function Looped(strFile As String, ws As Worksheet) As Boolean

Dim Found As Range
Set Found = ws.Range("F:F").Find(strFile)

If Found Is Nothing Then
Looped = False
Else
Looped = True
End If

End Function
```

**Here is attempt 1 using I simply change one of the vartemps into a range - unsurprisingly this did not work (No error - range is simply not copied)**

```
Sub CopyFromFolderExample()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4)
Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String, r As Long, wb As Workbook
Dim varTemp(1 To 6) As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
strFolder = "D:\Other\folder\"

'ws.Range("A2:E" & ws.Rows.Count).ClearContents
r = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.xl*")
Do While Len(strFile) > 0
    If Not Looped(strFile, ws) Then
        Application.StatusBar = "Reading data from " & strFile & "..."
        Set wb = Workbooks.Add(strFolder & strFile)
        With wb.Worksheets(1)
            varTemp(1) = strFile
            varTemp(2) = .Range("A13").Value
            varTemp(3) = .Range("H8").Value
            varTemp(4) = .Range("H9").Value
            varTemp(5) = .Range("H37").Value
            varTemp(6) = .Range("A20:A33").Value

        End With
        wb.Close False

        r = r + 1
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(r, 10), ws.Cells(r, 15)).Formula = varTemp
    End If
  strFile = Dir
Loop

Application.StatusBar = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

**Here is attempt 2 using selection.copy and selection.paste ("Object doesn't support this property or method" error with no workaround found:**

```
Sub CopyFromFolderExample()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4)
Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String, r As Long, wb As Workbook
Dim varTemp(1 To 6) As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
strFolder = "D:\Other\folder\"

'ws.Range("A2:E" & ws.Rows.Count).ClearContents
r = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.xl*")
Do While Len(strFile) > 0
    If Not Looped(strFile, ws) Then
        Application.StatusBar = "Reading data from " & strFile & "..."
        Set wb = Workbooks.Add(strFolder & strFile)
        With wb.Worksheets(1)
            varTemp(1) = strFile
            varTemp(2) = .Range("A13").Value
            varTemp(3) = .Range("H8").Value
            varTemp(4) = .Range("H9").Value
            varTemp(5) = .Range("H37").Value

.Range("A20:H33").Select
.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy

ws.Activate

If ws.Range("A1") = "" Then
ws.Range("A1").Select
Selection.Paste
Else
Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(6, 0).Select
Selection.Paste
End If

        End With
        wb.Close False

        r = r + 1
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(r, 10), ws.Cells(r, 15)).Formula = varTemp
    End If
  strFile = Dir
Loop

Application.StatusBar = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

**Here is attempt 3 using a modified sub that is incorporated into the main code:(Both range and cells are copied however I have been unable to incorporate this into the main code so the range is copied only if conditions are met):**

```
Sub CopyFromFolderExample()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4)
Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String, r As Long, wb As Workbook
Dim varTemp(1 To 6) As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
strFolder = "D:\Other\folder\"

'ws.Range("A2:E" & ws.Rows.Count).ClearContents
r = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.xl*")
Do While Len(strFile) > 0
    If Not Looped(strFile, ws) Then
        Application.StatusBar = "Reading data from " & strFile & "..."
        Set wb = Workbooks.Add(strFolder & strFile)
        With wb.Worksheets(1)
            varTemp(1) = strFile
            varTemp(2) = .Range("A13").Value
            varTemp(3) = .Range("H8").Value
            varTemp(4) = .Range("H9").Value
            varTemp(5) = .Range("H37").Value
            'varTemp(6) = .Range("A20:A33").Value

        End With
        wb.Close False

        r = r + 1
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(r, 10), ws.Cells(r, 15)).Formula = varTemp
    End If
  strFile = Dir
Loop

Application.StatusBar = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Dim xRg As Range
Dim xSelItem As Variant
Dim xFileDlg As FileDialog
Dim xFileName, xSheetName, xRgStr As String
Dim xBook, xWorkBook As Workbook
Dim xSheet As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
xSheetName = "DELIVERY NOTE"
xRgStr = "A20:H33"
Set xFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With xFileDlg
    If .Show = -1 Then
        xSelItem = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
        Set xWorkBook = ThisWorkbook
        Set xSheet = xWorkBook.Sheets("DN Compile")
        If xSheet Is Nothing Then

xWorkBook.Sheets.Add(after:=xWorkBook.Worksheets ---> 
--->(xWorkBook.Worksheets.Count)).Name = "DN Compile"
            Set xSheet = xWorkBook.Sheets("DN Compile")
        End If
        xFileName = Dir(xSelItem & "\*.xlsx", vbNormal)
        If xFileName = "" Then Exit Sub
        Do Until xFileName = ""
           Set xBook = Workbooks.Open(xSelItem & "\" & xFileName)
            Set xRg = xBook.Worksheets(xSheetName).Range(xRgStr)
            xRg.Copy xSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            xFileName = Dir()
            xBook.Close
        Loop
    End If
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Private Function Looped(strFile As String, ws As Worksheet) As Boolean

Dim Found As Range
Set Found = ws.Range("A:A").Find(strFile)

If Found Is Nothing Then
Looped = False
Else
Looped = True
End If

End Function
```

Comment: @urdearboy thought I would tag you in this as you have helped me develop the code! Thanks again!

Comment: You have provided a wish list, but what attempts and progress have you made?

Comment: Your post needs to demonstrate your attempt(s) and ask a specific **question**, otherwise you are simply asking someone to write your code for you.

Comment: I have tried many things, with some success however not quite what I am looking for. More specifically I have scoured the internet and found a few useful posts. Mostly subs that copy a range only and not certain cells and a range. I have been able to use this as a new section in the code and the range is copied as well as the cells however I cannot incorporate this into the code any better and the condition of copying ONLY from not looped files is not met. I have also tried incorporating selection.copy and selection.paste without success.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1188513)

Comment: Thanks guys, I will try and make sense of it all. I am new to all this so it is taking a while. @AndyG Does the comment above provide more clarification on the developments that I have tried undertaking?

Comment: @M.Laszkowski Explaining verbally what you have attempted is good, but still doesn't get beyond the "fill in the blanks for me" request. Actually providing the code attempt is necessary. On revisiting your attempts stick with one part of your tasklist, then your new question will be more focused and have some code to show what you have been trying.

Comment: I will edit the question asap with the two attempts that have come closest to giving me a result.

Comment: @M.Laszkowski I would have thought it better to start over with a new, more focused, single question.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem when copying a range into an array. What fixed it was using .Value2 instead of .Value. Might be worth a try.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either, I am guessing because the code was originally written to paste data into single rows and when I try to add code that also pastes blocks of data, it can't cope with that. I am yet to figure out why! Thanks for your input! I will try and re-work the question and post a new one like the guys have suggested in the comments.